# Is this a credible video footage of an unidentified flying object or unidentified aerial phenomena?

Tags: ufo

A nine-minute Navy video footage of a strange flying object as noted [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/groundbreaking-ufo-video-just-released-from-chilean_us_586d37bce4b014e7c72ee56b) and [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4095314/It-s-verified-UFO-Chile-release-footage-mystery-object-flying-navy-helicopter-two-year-investigation-fails-explain-it.html) was captured by two experienced Chilean Navy officers from a helicopter. This was also studied by Chilean military authority called CEFAA which comprises of committees of military experts, technicians and academics from many disciplines to investigate UFOs or UAP (unidentified aerial phenomena). Is this a credible video of a documented UFO event as reported by the Chilean Navy?

Comment: If it's a flying object that hasn't been identified then it is certainly an *unidentified flying object*. I'm guessing you mean something more (e.g., something that is probably an alien spacecraft; or something that is unlikely to fall into any commonplace category of aerial phenomenon). Perhaps make the question more specific?

Comment: Are you asking if the incident happened, or are you asking if this was an alien spacecraft?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, ventsyv-I wanted to know about the footage since another site actually doubts the video itself. More about that here-http://arstechnica.com/science/2017/01/after-two-years-of-study-chilean-officials-cant-explain-ufo-sighting/.

Comment: "Is this a credible video of a documented UFO event as reported by the Chilean Navy?" In the end, it depends on the credibility of the Chilean Navy. Mistakes can never really be ruled out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears that the report is largely true. CEFAA is an actual department within  DGAC, the Chilean agency that regulates aviation.
After some digging I found the official [release](http://www.cefaa.gob.cl/home/en-la-prensa/noticias/casoarmada) which did assign a Unidentified Aerial Phenomenon status to the claim. This seems to be the equivalent of UFO in US nomenclature.

This however does not mean it was an alien spacecraft. To paraphrase [Neil deGrasse Tyson](https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/541041098500890624)

> Just because you don't know what it is, doesn't mean it's aliens.

That's still true even if it was a bunch of very smart people who looked at the evidence. Sometimes there is simply not enough evidence to make a conclusion one way or the other.

Edit: It now appears that the sighting has been explained.

Mick West at Metabunk has used the location, heading, and time information of the helicopter and correlated it to air traffic data available on flightRadar24.com
He has determined that flight IB6830's flight path was in the field of view of the chopper at the time of the observation.
[image]

He argues that the blob on the sensor is glare from the engine of that airplane.
[image]

A very concise explanation is give in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uoqxr6AI7VQ

A detailed analysis is available here: https://www.metabunk.org/threads/explained-chilean-navy-ufo-video-aerodynamic-contrails-flight-ib6830.8306/

In view of the new analysis of the evidence, it appears the UFO has been identified as an airplane.

Comment: "Just because you don't know what it is, doesn't mean it's aliens" --> Tell that to Giorgio Tsoukalos. :)

Comment: @Luke Should I add the famous meme to my answer??

Comment: There is a claimed identification laid out here: https://www.metabunk.org/threads/explained-chilean-navy-ufo-video-aerodynamic-contrails-flight-ib6830.8306/

Comment: @ventsyv please adjust this Answer in regards to Harabeck'S comment - the metabunk explanation pulls this into IFO territory, not UFO

Comment: @bukwyrm Thanks.